# Find all linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that preserve the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2− z^2 = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I need to find all linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^3$  that preserve the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2− z^2 = 1$ . I could not come up with any good idea how to do this. \
The only thing I can do is to substitute in this equation $(ax+by+cz)$ instead of $x$, $(dx+ey+gz)$ instead of $y$, and $(hx+iy+jz)$ instead of $z$, so that these $(x,y,z)$ satisfy $x^2+y^2−z^2=1$, and it does not seem to give any nice result or I am too lazy to compute it properly. I did analogous computations with $x^2-y^2=1$ and that worked, but in this case I am stuck. Could anybody help?

Comment: A rotation around the $z$-axis will preserve the hyperboloid, for instance. I think you are meant to think geometrically, and confirm algebraically, not find all answers by solving the quite difficult equations.

Comment: Preservation = invariance? $T(G) = G$?

Comment: @mvw  yes you are right

Answer (score 5):

Define the matrix $D = \text{diag}(1,1,-1)$ and let $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ z \\ \end{bmatrix}$. Then the hyperboloid is $H = \{\mathbf{x} ~|~ \mathbf{x}^T D \mathbf{x} = x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1 \}$. Then a linear map $T$ preserves $H$ is equivalent to $$\mathbf{x}^T D \mathbf{x} = 1 \iff (T \mathbf{x})^T D (T\mathbf{x}) = 1$$.

A sufficient condition is $T^T D T = D$.

Comment: I might be a bit off track, but isn't this just the 3d analog of the famous mikowskian metric and related invariance in special relatvity?

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is to derive explicitly of what form these matrices are, like a parametrization or something. This can be done in the case of hyperbola, and I wonder if there is a nice way to obtain a parametrization in this case also.

Comment: Note that if $T$ is orthogonal then a sufficient condition is $T$ and $D$ commute. If you parameterize all 3D orthogonal matrices it won't be hard to determine which commute with $D$.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**
[image: hyperboloid]

The condition for the surface $H$ and the invariance $A(H) = H$ gives
\begin{align}
1 
&= x^2 + y^2 - z^2 \\
&= u^T (e_1, e_2, -e_3) u \\
&= u^T M_3 u \\
&= (Au)^T M_3 Au \\
&= u^T A^T M_3 Au
\end{align}
so we need $A$ with
$$
M_3 = A^T M_3 A \quad (*)
$$
where $M_3=(e_1,e_2,-e_3)$ is the reflection along the $z$-axis. 
One property is $M_3^2=I$.

**Orthogonal Solutions:**

Squaring both sides of $(*)$ gives:
$$
I = A^T M_3 A A^T M_3 A
$$
The middle part looks familiar. So certain orthogonal transformations ($A^TA=AA^T=I$) might be among the solutions of $(*)$, they would fulfill
$$
A M_3 = A A^T M_3 A = M_3 A \\
M_3 A^T = A^T M_3 A A^T = A^T M_3
$$
thus commute with $M_3$.

**Property of the Determinants:**
For the determinants of solutions of $(*)$ we have
$$
-1 = \det(A) (-1) \det(A) \iff
\det(A)^2 = 1 \iff \det(A) = \pm 1
$$
So the solution set of $(*)$ might include certain rotations $R$ (orthogonal, $\det R = 1$) and certain reflections $M$ (orthogonal, $\det(M) = -1$).

**Some Solutions:**

Candidates are $R_3$ (rotations around the $z$-axis) and $M_3$.
$$
M_3^T M_3 M_3 = M_3^T = M_3 
$$
So $M_3$ solves $(*)$. Now the rotation:
$$
R_3 =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & -\sin \phi & 0 \\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so
\begin{align}
R_3^T M_3 R_3 
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & \sin \phi & 0 \\
-\sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & -\sin \phi & 0 \\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & \sin \phi & 0 \\
-\sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & -\sin \phi & 0 \\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&= M_3
\end{align}

**Other Solutions:**
From 
\begin{align}
A^T M_3 A
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{21} & a_{31} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{32} \\
a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{21} & -a_{31} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & -a_{32} \\
a_{13} & a_{23} & -a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}^2 + a_{21}^2 - a_{31}^2 &
a_{11} a_{12} + a_{21} a_{22} - a_{31} a_{32} &
a_{11} a_{13} + a_{21} a_{23} - a_{31} a_{33}  
\\
a_{12} a_{11} + a_{22} a_{21} - a_{32} a_{31} & 
a_{12}^2 + a_{22}^2 - a_{32}^2 & 
a_{12} a_{13} + a_{22} a_{23} - a_{32} a_{33}
\\
a_{13} a_{11} + a_{23} a_{21} - a_{33} a_{31} &
a_{13} a_{12} + a_{23} a_{22} - a_{33} a_{32} &
a_{13}^2 + a_{23}^2 - a_{33}^2
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
we get the six equations
$$
a_{11}^2 + a_{21}^2 - a_{31}^2 = 1 \\
a_{12}^2 + a_{22}^2 - a_{32}^2 = 1 \\
a_{13}^2 + a_{23}^2 - a_{33}^2 = -1 \\
a_{11} a_{12} + a_{21} a_{22} - a_{31} a_{32} = 0 \\
a_{11} a_{13} + a_{21} a_{23} - a_{31} a_{33} = 0 \\
a_{12} a_{13} + a_{22} a_{23} - a_{32} a_{33} = 0
$$

I have tried out a few samples, choosing different free variables, but did not manage to produce a non-orthogonal solution yet.

Comment: Yes, this is all clear. But in the case of hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ there exist not orthogonal transformations that preserve it, for instance, if $x'=ax+by$ and $y'=cx+dy$, then setting $a=d=(1+t^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=c=t$ and substituting $x'$ and $y'$ (provided that x and y are on the hyperbola) in the equation shows that this transformation preserve hyperbola and yet it is not orthogonal. I do understand that orthogonal transformations preserve the hyperboloid, but there might be non-orthogonal ones, and I wish to know if there is any way to determine all of them explicitly

Comment: I meant that "I do understand that there are orthogonal transformations preserving the hyperboloid", sorry

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Start with parametrization

$$(x,y,z)= { \sec u \cos v, \, \sec u \sin v, \, \tan u\,}$$

where $u$ parametrization caters for the skew straight line generation for given $v$ .. which in turn serves to generate the hyperboloid swept surface of revolution.